# apache shiro allowing multiple roles to Access a url not working

Tags: shiro

I have a simple web project. I want to have access to more than one role in this project is a URL.

sihor.ini section of the url

```
[urls]
/login.xhtml = authc
/logout = logout
/admin/** = user, roles[admin]
/guest/** = user, roles[admin,guest]
```

I'm getting a 401 error when the role of a user admin visit to guest directory.

Why?

shiro version 1.2.1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's another option: custom implementation of roles filter using `OR` for the provided role set instead of `AND`.

```java
import org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject;
import org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authz.RolesAuthorizationFilter;

import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Allows access if current user has at least one role of the specified list.
 * 
 * Basically, it's the same as {@link RolesAuthorizationFilter} but using {@literal OR} instead
 * of {@literal AND} on the specified roles.
 *
 * @see RolesAuthorizationFilter
 * @author Andy Belsky
 */
public class AnyOfRolesAuthorizationFilter extends RolesAuthorizationFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean isAccessAllowed(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                                   Object mappedValue) throws IOException {

        final Subject subject = getSubject(request, response);
        final String[] rolesArray = (String[]) mappedValue;

        if (rolesArray == null || rolesArray.length == 0) {
            //no roles specified, so nothing to check - allow access.
            return true;
        }

        for (String roleName : rolesArray) {
            if (subject.hasRole(roleName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The usage in `shiro.ini` is like this:

```
[main]
...
anyofroles = com.your.package.AnyOfRolesAuthorizationFilter

[urls]
...
/path/to/some/url = anyofroles["role1,role2"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

`/guest/** = user, roles[admin,guest]`

try out

```
/guest/** = user, roles[admin],roles[guest]
```

Comment: Great idea, but sadly this doesn't work as each role check is enforced.